# "Shake to locate cursor" feature

Tags: linux, mouse, cursor, mouse-gestures

I was wondering if there is a feature in linux like OSX "shake to locate cursor", which temporarily makes the user's mouse or trackpad cursor much larger when shaken back and forth, making it easier to locate if the user loses track of it.

Comment: Can't think of one, but that sounds like a nice project.

Comment: Related, over at Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/569274/is-there-a-locate-pointer-helper-in-lubuntu-for-visually-impaired

Comment: Keeping xeyes running is more helpful than I thought, send to all panes of your desktop.  When you can't find the cursoe, wiggle the mouse or touchpad and watch the eyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux Mint (18.1) you can go to Preferences > Mouse and, under Locate Pointer you can check a box that will tell the system to "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed".

I'm not sure if something similar is available on other distros.

Not quite what you asked for. Possibly useful?

Comment: For me, this was not effective when the pointer is over a black background. The "locator" ripples black circles which can't be seen :-(

Comment: it is also not so acceptable option, since it overlaps with the thousands of situations where you need the ctr key as modifier... :-/
The "ctr" functionality is preserved, as modifier key, but yo keep seeing the "waves" effect, which sometimes is annoying.

Answer (score 10):

You can do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYcMQ.gif) on any GNOME based distro using **[dconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf)** (part of GNOME, replacement of GConf) on **org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse**, parameter **locate-pointer**.

#### CLI way

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

On newer versions of Gnome [seems to be](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/818) on this path:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true
```

To use `Shift_R` instead of `Control_L`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter locate-pointer-key Shift_R
```

#### GUI way

Open **dconf-editor** (might be installed first) and go to one of the above paths:

[image: dconf-editor screenshot]

Another alternative (more Mac-style) is to use [Jiggle GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3438/jiggle/).

### KDE

On [KDE Plasma 6](https://pointieststick.com/2023/12/01/this-week-in-kde-changing-the-wallpaper-from-within-system-settings/) beta (2023-12-01):

> Implemented a “Shake to find your cursor” KWin effect, similar to the one in macOS. Note that it’s off by default for now, so you’ll need to manually turn it on in System Settings’ Desktop Effects page if you want to use it (Vlad Zahorodnii, link)

### Reference

- [settings - How do I turn off "show mouse" when I press Ctrl? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/230113/349837)

Comment: On my Ubuntu 19.10, that doesn't work, there is no locate-pointer key.

Comment: Can't get this (or any other solution) to work for 20.10.

Comment: @Snowcrash I'm on 18..04/Gnome 3.28.4. Check if it is on `org.gnome.desktop.interface` as [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/818) issue suggest.

Comment: You might also be interested to remap the key instead of Left Control. Simply set `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter locate-pointer-key Shift_R`. I tested it on U21.04, but I think it has been there already since GNOME 3.36.

Comment: This works fine for me except the animations is so small and low-contrast that I still can't find my pointer using my peripheral vision.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an excellent shake to find cursor package at the following github project: https://github.com/jeffchannell/jiggle

It took me a moment to find out how to install it though, so here it is for future reference:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3438/jiggle/

Comment: Here's a standalone .py file. Put it whereever and make it executable: https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/666cf32a12f7f1e60ddd0e20cf4746a1

Answer (score 1):

The setting of `locate-pointer` seems to have moved, I found it here in my Fedora 31: `org/gnome/desktop/interface/locate-pointer`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true
```